# loading XML file into MySQL

Tags: mysql, xml

I have to get values from XML file.
I tried LOAD XML INFILE but I have some problem with children tags
My XML structure is like following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<list>
        <cli>
        <num_id>120</num_id>
        <contact>
            <nom>DUPOND</nom>
            <prenom>Pierre</prenom>
        </contact>
        <relation>253</relation>
        <adresse>
            <adresse_c>route de la mer</adresse_c>
            <code_postal>64200</code_postal>
            <ville>Biarritz</ville>
        </adresse>
    </cli>
    <cli>
        <num_id>121</num_id>
        <contact>
            <nom>Henry</nom>
            <prenom>Claude</prenom>
        </contact>
        <relation>511</relation>
        <adresse>
            <adresse_c>rue de blabla</adresse_c>
            <code_postal>75001</code_postal>
            <ville>Paris</ville>
        </adresse>
    </cli>
</list>
```

How can do? Thank you.

***EDIT:***
I need to get values from each tag to insert in a database.
My database structure is :

```
CREATE table client (
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    num_id INT(5) NOT NULL,
    nom VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    prenom VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    relation INT(5) NOT NULL,
    adresse_c VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
    code_postal INT(5) NOT NULL,
    ville VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
)
```

I tried `LOAD XML INFILE 'test.xml' INTO TABLE infos.client ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<cli>';`

But I have only values from num_id and relation.
Values from children tags(nom, prenom, adresse_c, code_postal, ville>) are not getting.
How can i get all others values?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a blob column (i.e. mediumtext column) or
Try using  LOAD XML command.

Comment: i did => LOAD XML INFILE 'test.xml' INTO TABLE tableInfos.testxml ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<cli>';
But it miss  all values from children tags